# Greasemonkey script that parses JSON to display some extra info on FamilySearch.org

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

This is my first Greasemonkey script and I'd like to get some comments/criticism on the code. It's pretty short so I'll just paste the whole thing here.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @author Jamie22
// @name FamilySearch Relationship Name
// @version 0.1
// @description Script for FamilySearch.org that describes the relationship between you and another person on your family tree when you click "View My Relationship", ie. Grandmother, 3 Times Great Grandfather, 4th Cousin Twice Removed, etc.
// @match https://familysearch.org/tree/*
// @copyright 2017 James Shorrock
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant GM_addStyle
// @license GPL3; https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html
// ==/UserScript==

// This will be used to display the relationship name on the page
var rlNameSpan = null;

waitForKeyElements("#show", addShowListener);

function addShowListener()
{
    document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", getFamilyJSON);
}

function getFamilyJSON()
{
    var ancestorId = window.location.pathname.split('/')[3];

    $.getJSON('https://familysearch.org/tree-data/my-relatives/tree-graph-relation/' + window.eval('loggedInPersonId') + '/' + ancestorId, nameRelationship);
}

function grand(rel, numgen)
{
    if (numgen >= 2)
        rel = "Grand" + rel;

    if (numgen >= 3)
        rel = "Great " + rel;

    if (numgen == 4)
        rel = "Great " + rel;

    if (numgen >= 5)
        rel = (numgen - 2) + ' Times ' + rel;

    return rel;
}

function ordinalSuffixOf(i)
{
    var j = i % 10,
        k = i % 100;

    if (j == 1 && k != 11)
        return i + "st";

    if (j == 2 && k != 12)
        return i + "nd";

    if (j == 3 && k != 13)
        return i + "rd";

    return i + "th";
}

function nameRelationship(relChart)
{
    var isDiffBranch = false;
    var isInLaw = false;
    // 1 for up, -1 for down
    var direction = 0;
    var numGenerationsUp = 0;
    var numGenerationsDown = 0;
    var persons = relChart.data.persons;
    var ancestorGender = persons[persons.length-1].gender;

    // Travese the people in the relationship chart
    for(var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++)
    {
        if (!persons[i].relationshipToPrevious)
            continue;

        if (persons[i].relationshipToPrevious == "FATHER" || persons[i].relationshipToPrevious == "MOTHER")
        {
            direction = 1;
            numGenerationsUp++;
        }

        if (persons[i].relationshipToPrevious == "SON" || persons[i].relationshipToPrevious == "DAUGHTER")
        {
            if (direction == 1)
                isDiffBranch = true;

            direction = -1;
            numGenerationsDown++;
        }

        if (persons[i].relationshipToPrevious == "MAN" || persons[i].relationshipToPrevious == "WOMAN")
            isInLaw = true;
    }

    var relationship = '';
    var numGenerations = 0;

    // Direct ancestor or descendant
    if (!isDiffBranch)
    {
        if (direction == 1)
        {
            if (ancestorGender == "FEMALE")
                relationship = "mother";
            else
                relationship = "father";

            numGenerations = numGenerationsUp;
        }
        else
        {
            if (ancestorGender == "FEMALE")
                relationship = "daughter";
            else
                relationship = "son";

            numGenerations = numGenerationsDown;
        }

        relationship = grand(relationship, numGenerations);
    }
    else
    {
        // Sibling
        if (numGenerationsUp == 1 && numGenerationsDown == 1)
        {
            if (ancestorGender == "FEMALE")
                relationship = "Sister";
            else
                relationship = "Brother";
        }

        // Niece or nephew
        if (numGenerationsUp == 1 && numGenerationsDown >= 2)
        {
            if (ancestorGender == "FEMALE")
                relationship = "niece";
            else
                relationship = "nephew";

            relationship = grand(relationship, numGenerationsDown-1);
        }

        // Uncle or aunt
        if (numGenerationsUp >= 2 && numGenerationsDown == 1)
        {
            if (ancestorGender == "FEMALE")
                relationship = "aunt";
            else
                relationship = "uncle";

            relationship = grand(relationship, numGenerationsUp-1);
        }

        // Cousin
        if (numGenerationsUp >= 2 && numGenerationsDown >= 2)
        {
            var cousinNum = Math.min(numGenerationsUp, numGenerationsDown)-1;
            var removedNum = Math.abs(numGenerationsUp - numGenerationsDown);

            relationship = ordinalSuffixOf(cousinNum) + ' Cousin';

            if (removedNum == 1)
                relationship += ' Once Removed';

            if (removedNum == 2)
                relationship += ' Twice Removed';

            if (removedNum >= 3)
                relationship += ' ' + removedNum + ' Times Removed';
        }

        if (isInLaw)
            relationship += ' In-Law';
    }

    // Capitalize first letter
    relationship = relationship.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + relationship.slice(1);

    // Display the relationship name at the bottom of the relationship chart popup
    if(rlNameSpan === null)
    {
        // Works in Firefox
        var infoIcon = document.getElementById("info-icon");

        if(infoIcon === null)
            // Works in Chrome
            infoIcon = document.getElementsByTagName("birch-relationship-calc")[0].shadowRoot.querySelector("#info-icon");

        rlNameSpan = document.createElement('span');
        rlNameSpan.style.fontSize = "18px";
        rlNameSpan.style.paddingLeft = "100px";
        infoIcon.parentNode.insertBefore(rlNameSpan, infoIcon.nextSibling);
    }

    rlNameSpan.innerHTML = relationship;
}
```